# comparing multiple column files using python3

Tags: file, python-3.x, comparison

input_file1:

```
a  1 33
a 34 67
a 68 78
b  1 99
b 100 140
c  1 70
c 71 100
c 101 190
```

input file2:

```
a  5 23
a 30 72
a 76 78
b  5 30
c 23 88
c 92 98
```

I want to compare these two files such that for every value of `'a'` in file2 the two integers (boundary) fall in the range (boundaries) of `'a'` in file1 or between two ranges.

Comment: Can you show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do?or the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: actually i  want to use python3 but unable to make a key because of multiple occurrence of variables 'a' , 'b', and 'c'.

Comment: Sorry but So is not a *pleas do it for me* website.If you want to get a proper answer you need to add the code that you have tried by yourself, and explain about your problem! with adding the expected output!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing values like this 'a 1 33', you can make one structure (like 'a:1:33') for your data while writing into file. So that it will become easy to read data also.

Then, you can read each line and can split it based on ':' separator and you can compare with another file easily.